# Issue with making Number Tables Program (like 12 x 1 = 12) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, scope, nan

I am trying to make a program that produces maths tables for any number like so:

3 x 1 = 3

3 x 2 = 6

3 x 3 = 9

3 x 4 = 12

I need the user to input:

(1) Any number they need the table for (eg -  3)

(2) specify a start point (eg - 1)

(3) Specify an end point (eg - 4)

My flawed code so far is as follows:

```js
    function isitanumber(numb){
        while (isNaN(numb) == true){
           numb = parseInt(prompt("Please add a valid number","5"));
          }
         }
    
    
    function mytable (thenum, first, second){
        for (var i=first; i<=second; i++){
         var y = thenum*i;
         document.write(thenum + " x " + i + " = " + y + "</br>");
         }
        }
    
    
    var mynum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number you wish to have the table for", "40"));
    mynum = isitanumber(mynum);
    
    
    var startpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the startpoint of the table", "1")); 
    mynum = isitanumber(startpoint);
    
    var endpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the endpoint of the table", "10"));  
    mynum = isitanumber(endpoint);
    
    
    mytable(mynum,startpoint,endpoint);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Whenever I put in letters on the first prompt and then put digits on the second prompt, it gives me NaN. Specifically, I need to find out how to get access to the last value that the user enters which turns isNaN false.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what your variables are.

Comment: There are some issues with your code; you declare mynum 3 times. You have to change the last two to startpoint and endpoint. Also you need to return numb after the while loop. http://codepen.io/peerbolte/pen/pRoPQx?editors=1111

Comment: parseInt() will remove letters after numbers, not the other way round. so parseInt('123abc') will return '123'. Also, i'd recommend always specifying a radix to the parseInt method, ie parseInt('123abc',10). The 10 indicates it's a decimal number, not a hex, or binary or whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isitanumber` returns `undefined` (default value returned by functions without a `return` statement) that you assign to `mynum` every time (`mynum = isitanumber(...)`). Therefore, `mynum` contains `undefined` value.

You should return the variable as you finish to loop the `NaN`s (and assign it to the appropriate variable):

```js
function isitanumber(numb)
{
    while (isNaN(numb)) {
            numb = parseInt(prompt("Please add a valid number","5"));
    }
    return numb;
}

function mytable (num, start, end)
{
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        var y = num * i;
        document.write(num + " x " + i + " = " + y + "</br>");
    }
}

var mynum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number you wish to have the table for", "40"));
mynum = isitanumber(mynum);

var startpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the startpoint of the table", "1")); 
startpoint = isitanumber(startpoint);

var endpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the endpoint of the table", "10"));  
endpoint = isitanumber(endpoint);

mytable(mynum, startpoint, endpoint);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply! Have been stuck on this code for last 8hrs and i think i am brain dead now. One quick question - why does adding "return" make it work? What did it change in the process flow of code? Thanks

Comment: @nishkaush: Well, without it, your function doesn't return a value. But you're trying to use the value returned by the function. Can you see how that was not going to work?

Comment: sorry i am new to JS and still figuring out how things work. I was told not to use return because it ends functions and loops and should be the last choice. but clearly it saved my code here.

Comment: @nishkaush if you don't add `return` it will return `undefined` by default (which goes into `mynum`) [see in the answer]

Answer (score 0):

You made the following mistakes:

**function return value,
assigning startpoint variable,
assigning endpoint variable**

```js
function isitanumber(numb){
    while (isNaN(numb) == true){
            numb = parseInt(prompt("Please add a valid number","5"));
        }
        return numb;
     }


function mytable (thenum, first, second){
    for (var i=first; i<=second; i++){
        var y = thenum*i;
        document.write(thenum + " x " + i + " = " + y + "</br>");
     }
    }


var mynum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number you wish to have the table for", "40"));
mynum = isitanumber(mynum);


var startpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the startpoint of the table", "1")); 
startpoint = isitanumber(startpoint);

var endpoint = parseInt(prompt("Enter the endpoint of the table", "10"));  
endpoint = isitanumber(endpoint);


mytable(mynum,startpoint,endpoint);
```